# Could not load conf for core collection1: Error loading solr config from<Path to solrconfig.xml>/solrconfig.xml. Where is this setting done?

Tags: solr

While trying to war file which creates a solr server, I get below error. Not sure where exactly this setting is done.

ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer- Error creating core [collection1]: Could not load conf for core collection1: Error loading solr config from /apps/tomcat/mcbuk_chef_traqs/traqsIndex/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core collection1: Error loading solr config from /apps/tomcat/mcbuk_chef_traqs/traqsIndex/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml
at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:66)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:489)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:255)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading solr config from /apps/tomcat/mcbuk_chef_traqs/traqsIndex/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml

I was expecting the application to start cleanly, as the war was taken from another server with exactly same settings and directory structure.

Comment: Does the path match the old server or the new one? Is the file present in the given path? Generally `solr.xml` can configure some options - since you seem ti be using tomcat there might be some environment settings there as well (usually you'd configure these in the startup script as arguments to solr).

Comment: As per my configuration in solr.xml I have created two cores, but it is not picking the core of my configuration. I do not know from where it si trying to pick  collection1 as core.